# 403 Forbidden Yii2 basic

Tags: yii2, composer, http-status-code-404

Я установил yii2 через композер в папку /var/www/site
Сборка basic,
сервер на ubuntu 16.04 в локальной сети.

по адрессу site.ru ловлю 403 ошибку

В папке /var/www/site нет index.php
Вычитал что надо провести инициализацию проекта. Как это сделать ?
команда

```
php /var/www/site init
```

запускается на секунду , и снова вижу приглашение ubunt`ы

```
user@machine:/#
```

В папке с проектом index.php не создался , все также 403 ошибка.
Что я делаю(не делаю) не так?

В логах nginx

```
[error] directory index of "/var/www/site" is forbidden ......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у вас нет прав на папку "site" Ошибка 403 это ошибка доступа

Comment: спасибо я разобрался, проблема была в том что виртуальный хост apache2 был настроен на другую папку, к которой действительно небыло доступа, из-за неправильных прав.